# Will a higher voltage to get the desired current hurt RGB LEDs?

Tags: power-supply, led, dc

I have 29 RGB LEDs connected in parallel and will control them with PWM.

They can handle 20 mA per color. I was planning to supply them with 5V and measured the voltage drop per block at 20x29 = 580mA input 5V.

- Blue drops 3.06V so resistor needed: 3.9 ohm
- Red drops 2.15V so resistor needed: 5.6 ohm
- Green drops 2.95 so resistor needed: 3.9 ohm

Combined resistance: 1.45 ohm

The cable is a common UTP CAT6 cable I merged the ends so 8m of wire and measured with 2 multimeters and it's 3 Ω. This is the problem. The total resistance is 4.45 ohm and that is max 1123 mA instead of the desired 1740 mA

Can I do a 9V supply to get the current with adjusted resistor values or will it hurt the LEDs?

They won't be running at ful power all the time, PWM will adjust the colors so power dissipation should not be an issue.

Unfortunately I can't find the datasheet. Part number EVERLIGHT EVL-504-90-CA

Comment: How will you limit current on 1st LED with 9V and fixed R?  That’s too much. You need heavy power rails https://www.hestore.hu/prod_10037597.html

Comment: For 10% load regulation with 3.9 Ohms your cable loop resistance must be lower

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://www.hestore.hu/prod_10037597.html  These specs are very wide tolerance so your performance will suffer with your design.  1.8..2.4 / 2.8..4 / 2.8..4V  assume nominal for RGB is 2V , 3.4V, 3.4V

Comment: Are you planning to use AWG 30 magnet wire?

Comment: This is the design I'm stuck with not a lot of room. Parallel is not the best, but LEDS are from the same batch and first tests seem to be even lit. So I would do 9v with a resistor of 12ohm to get the 580mA combined current for one color. Would a led survive it or that 4v limit is the max and not the current that count?

Comment: The wire is a common cheap UTP CAT6 cable.

Comment: OK AWG 84.22 mOhm /m , how did you measure 3 Ohms and your R calculations are wrong , try 80 Ohms . 100, 100 minus your PWM R

Comment: Twisted the ends so measurement is for 8m. Maybe it's a bad cable.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/pReQRoXugoRBvtVGA
How did you arrive at 80, what am I overlooking, the voltage drop will be smaller?

Comment: My bad, I meant 100,80,80 5-3V=2V/100=20mA , 5-3.4=1.6/80=20mA

Comment: No wonder the wire was cheap, AWG30 ish

Comment: Yeah 100 is good for 1 led but I have 29 in parallel so the mA should be 29x20 = 580 then 2 / 0.580 = 3.45 nearest resistor value: 3.9 ohm.
The question is will this work at 9V

Comment: These LEDs better be matched much better than specs, otherwise you will have thermal runaway (burnout) on the lowest Vf. There is a current hogging effect and NTC response.  No I wouldn’t use 9V. It’s better to design for more stable currents.

Comment: If the LEDs are in parallel you should have one resistor per LED.  Paralleled LEDs don't share current well and all LEDs are subject to risk of thermal runaway.  Note that if you run 3V or lower LEDs off 9V you will waste a *ton* of power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do a 9V supply to get the current with adjusted resistor values or will it hurt the leds?

So long as the current through each LED is correct, the LEDs don't care what the supply voltage is.

But if you are controlling the LEDs individually, beware that the voltage drop along the cable will depend on the current, which will depend on how many LEDs you have on at one time.  You could find that turning one LED on and off causes the other LEDs to flicker.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't any different for RGB LEDs than for any other set of 3 LEDs:

You can't put them in parallel with a single series resistor. Every color LED needs its own resistor.

> but my 4m power cable is 3 ohm an this is the problem

Yes. This means you need a better cable. I don't know *which* cable you're using, but even a single 0.180 mm diameter copper wire strand ([AWG 33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge), that is *literally* as thin as the average human hair) has lower resistance than that... My guess is you have a measurement artifact in there, and there's no problem at all.

Comment: The cable is a common UTP CAT6 cable I merged the ends so 8m of wire and measured with 2 multimeters ant it's 3ohms. But those have a really good price for a 8 strand wire also twisted pairs will help with high speed I2C and PMW. 

Leds will be parallel the design is too complex and not a lot of room for individual resistors, but they are from the same batch and tested them, seem to be even so that is what I'm stuck with for now...

Comment: you're still not measuring properly, or you got bad cable. Cat-6 is AWG 24 at least, so 4m would have about 0.33 Ω of resistance. Twisted pair helps not that much with non-differential signalling like in I²C or PWM signals. Shielding might help, but you're much more the interference aggressor than the receiver of interference, so meh.

Comment: Price is the main selling point, I could get 20m dirt cheep. I twisted the end of a pair, and measured at the end. The combined length is 8m and it is 3ohms unless both my meters are off but unlikely.

Comment: 24AWG = 84.22mOhm /m * 8m * 2 wire = 1.35 Ohm

Comment: 5m Stripleds are dirt cheap with a remote control

Comment: Maybe the wire is bad, and that's why it's cheap donno :)
https://photos.app.goo.gl/pReQRoXugoRBvtVGA

Comment: I usually use WS2812B led stips, but this is a very special arrangement

Comment: You can improve results greatly by driving power at both ends

Comment: No more room, I need 2 I2C, 3 PWM, 1 GND, 1 5V0, only 1 left for a higher power. Main question is if we assume Leds are the same can it be done with higher voltage?

Comment: @Reider - LEDs, like all diodes, drop a voltage. They don't work anymore if they flow too much current. A Mirrabella globe I tore down yesterday has 17 SMD leds and a BP5131D LED driver. The driver is a constant current one. I put 240v in one side and it runs how ever many LEDs I want on the other side. It performs essentially, the same task as a dropper resistor - to make the excess voltage not be presented on the legs of the device. ;)

Comment: Yeah that would be good unfortunately max voltage I have is a 12v battery also series connection would be hard to wire where I need it. If I had more time I would do it with WS2812B smd leds. They have everything built in, but much more difficult to arrange in the pattern I need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no voltage limit for LEDS if you adjust the current and power dissipation accordingly. So it should work with 9V and the proper resistor. The parallel connection is not a great idea but that would have to do for now. Thanks everyone.